# Retrieve the path of a git repository

Tags: git

I created on my server a git repository with commands:

```
$ cd /var/www/html
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'inital commit'
```

Now, i need to clone this repository on my local machine. How can i retrieve the correct path for git clone?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use any git server you can clone it from ssh:

```
git clone ssh://YOURSSHUSER@YOURSERVERIP:sshport/var/www/html/.git
```

For example:

```
git clone ssh://itsme@100.100.100.100:22/var/www/html/.git
```

Comment: note that ssh also needs some configuration, depending on the OS OP is using

Comment: above will not work, needed to git init with --bare in server.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up an empty repository by running git init with the --bare option, which initializes the repository without a working directory:

```
$ cd /srv/git
$ mkdir project.git
$ cd project.git
$ git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /srv/git/project.git/
```

Then on your computer,

```
$ cd myproject
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'initial commit'
$ git remote add origin git@gitserver:/srv/git/project.git
$ git push origin master
```

At this point, you can clone it down and push changes back up just as easily:

```
$ git clone git@gitserver:/srv/git/project.git
$ cd project
$ vim README
$ git commit -am 'fix for the README file'
$ git push origin master
```

Reference: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server